# Tint color of UIImage in XIB

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xib

I was trying different things, but haven't found an answer for this question.
Is there a way how to tint color of an image which is defined by UIImageView in XIB file?

thanx

Comment: I donot think it is possible.

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithBurnTint:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIImage *img = self;

    // lets tint the icon - assumes your icons are black
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, img.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);

    // draw alpha-mask
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

    // draw tint color, preserving alpha values of original image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);
    [color setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return coloredImage;

}
```

And then

```
[anImageViewInXib setImage:[center.image imageWithBurnTint:[UIColor blackColor]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to change your button type for **System**

[image]

Then you will be able to manage tint color of your image

The result is on the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.for tint image

```
@interface UIImage (Additions)
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color;

#import "UIImage+Additions.h"

@implementation UIImage (Additions)

+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: tried something similar (the rectangle in your code is not according to the actual picture size) but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new iOS7 apis to do this.

```
        UIImage *image = [self.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        imageView.image = image;
        imageView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

First step is to get the existing image and make a copy of that image with the rendering mode set to template. Set the image returned back onto the imageView and finally set the tint colour on the image view.

Comment: You can use `-imageWithRenderingMode:` directly on `UIImage` -- you don't need to put it in an image view first.

Comment: @MikeRhodes yes that is correct. I was just posting up code in the context of the @Vanya question. He was trying to tint a image in an imageview from a nib. So I posted an example of code he could put `awakeFromNib` that would tint any image he put inside that uiimageivew in the nib.